# ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (D:\PROJECT-MASA-KULIAH\be_vue_crud\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)

Tags: flask

can anyone help solve this problem?

File "D:\PROJECT-MASA-KULIAH\be_vue_crud\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
**import**(module_name)
File "D:\PROJECT-MASA-KULIAH\be_vue_crud\db_crud_vue.py", line 2, in 
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
File "D:\PROJECT-MASA-KULIAH\be_vue_crud\venv\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 7, in 
from flask import _request_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack
ImportError: cannot import name '*request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (D:\PROJECT-MASA-KULIAH\be_vue_crud\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_*init**.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: cannot import name '\_request\_ctx\_stack' from 'flask'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240858/how-to-fix-cannot-import-name-request-ctx-stack-from-flask)